# <input> type button/submit taking extra space on right

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I am having an `<input type="button">` for one of my project. for IE7 it takes extra padding on the right side for no reason. Only IE7 has this issue, I have tried everything I could.

any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much in advance for helping.

**HTML**
`<input type="button" value="Sign up" class="defaultBtn" />`

**CSS**
`.defaultBtn {
    outline:none;  padding:0;
    text-indent:0;
border:0; 
            margin:0;
            background: #FF7200;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            display: block;
            font: 1.4em Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
            }`

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: Is the input inside of a table cell (td) or a div tag

Comment: it is inside a div, actually even if I put it all by it self direct into body it's the same.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2523248/2987685

Comment: @Veronica thanks you! this is what I have been looking for. Thanks again

Comment: possible duplicate of [Buttons size not equal in IE and Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523232/buttons-size-not-equal-in-ie-and-firefox)